# My if statement does not work in my whois command | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

so I'm making a whois command and the if statement I'm making makes it so that if the user does not have roles, the value=None. However, Im having trouble with it. Here's the code

```py
  @commands.command(aliases=["whois"])
  async def userinfo(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
      if not member: 
        member = ctx.message.author
      embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(random.randint(1, 16777215)), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,title=f"User Info - {member}")
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
      embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.name)
      embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
      embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=member.display_name)
      embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
      embed.add_field(name="Created Account On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M  UTC"))
      embed.add_field(name="Joined Server On:", value=(member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC")))
      roles = [role.mention for role in member.roles[1:]]
      embed.add_field(name=f"Roles({len(roles)}):",value=",".join(roles), 
      inline=False)
      embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      if roles == None: 
        embed.add_field(name="Roles", value="None", inline=False)
```

So I asked my friend who is good at python and he send me this:

```py
  @commands.command(aliases=["whois"])
  async def userinfo(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
      if not member: 
        member = ctx.message.author
      embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(random.randint(1, 16777215)), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,title=f"User Info - {member}")
      embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
      embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.name)
      embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
      embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=member.display_name)
      embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
      embed.add_field(name="Created Account On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M  UTC"))
      embed.add_field(name="Joined Server On:", value=(member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC")))
      roles = [role.mention for role in member.roles[1:]]
      if roles == None:    embed.add_field(name=f"Roles({len(roles)}):",value=",".join(roles), inline=False)
      embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This is the error

```
In embed.fields.6.value: This field is required
```

It works but the problem is that it shows the @@everyone role, How can I get rid of the @@everyone role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed code, the `@everyone` role is always the first role of the member so just exclude him by accessing the list from the second element: `member.roles[1:]`, also when you try to send an embed but the user has no roles other than the `@everyone` role it will spit out an error because the `roles` list is empty, so you must include checks to prevent inserting an empty value.

```py
commands.command(aliases=["whois"])
async def userinfo(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member: 
        member = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour(random.randint(1, 16777215)), timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,title=f"User Info - {member}")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar_url)
    embed.add_field(name="Name", value=member.name)
    embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=member.id)
    embed.add_field(name="Nickname:", value=member.display_name)
    embed.add_field(name="Status", value=member.status)
    embed.add_field(name="Created Account On:", value=member.created_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M  UTC"))
    embed.add_field(name="Joined Server On:", value=(member.joined_at.strftime("%a, %#d %B %Y, %I:%M %p UTC")))

    # Fixed part
    roles = [role.mention for role in member.roles[1:]]

    if len(member.roles[1:]) < 1:
        embed.add_field(name=f"Roles:",value="None", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value="None")
    elif roles != None:
        embed.add_field(name=f"Roles({len(roles)}):",value=",".join(roles), inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value=member.top_role.mention)
    # End of fix
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: btw you can use `\u200b` as a empty line instead of `None`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am aware of the \u200b, but I thought "None" would look better